# PyQt5 closeEvent method

Tags: python, oop, pyqt, pyqt5

I'm currently learning how to build an application with pyqt5 and encountered some problem with closeEvent method, overriden so user gets asked for confirmation by QMessageBox object. It seems working well with X button - event gets 'accepted' when action is confirmed and 'canceled' when cancel button is clicked. However, when I use my Quit button from dropdown File menu, no matter which button I click, program gets closed with exit code 1. Seems strange, because I use same closeEvent method in both cases.

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMessageBox, QMainWindow, QAction


class window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):

        super().__init__()

    def createUI(self):


        self.setGeometry(500, 300, 700, 700)

        self.setWindowTitle("window")


        quit = QAction("Quit", self)
        quit.triggered.connect(self.closeEvent)

        menubar = self.menuBar()
        fmenu = menubar.addMenu("File")
        fmenu.addAction(quit)

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        close = QMessageBox()
        close.setText("You sure?")
        close.setStandardButtons(QMessageBox.Yes | QMessageBox.Cancel)
        close = close.exec()

        if close == QMessageBox.Yes:
            event.accept()
        else:
            event.ignore()

main = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = window()
window.createUI()
window.show()
sys.exit(main.exec_())
```

Thanks for suggestions!

Comment: did you run it in console/terminal ? You have error message. `AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'accept'`

Comment: when you click button then system call your function but with different `event` object which doesn't have `accept()` and `ignore()` so you get error message and program ends with exit code 1.

Answer (score 10):

When you click button then program calls your function but with different `event` object which doesn't have `accept()` and `ignore()` so you get error message and program ends with exit code 1.

You can assign `self.close` and program will call `closeEvent()` with correct event object.

```
quit.triggered.connect(self.close)
```

Comment: In my case, `self.close` gives `AttributeError` and `self.closeEvent` works but doesn't trigger `closeEvent()`

Answer (score 9):

The problem is accept is a method while ignore is just an attribute.
This code works for me:

```
def closeEvent(self, event):
            close = QtWidgets.QMessageBox.question(self,
                                         "QUIT",
                                         "Are you sure want to stop process?",
                                         QtWidgets.QMessageBox.Yes | QtWidgets.QMessageBox.No)
            if close == QtWidgets.QMessageBox.Yes:
                event.accept()
            else:
                event.ignore()
```

Comment: How can this code work for you? What does the 'self' refer to in your code? In my code 'self' refers to QMainWindow. Your code does not work for me.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and fixed with a type-check-hack. It might be an ugly hack, but it works (tested on macOS 10.15 with python 3.8.0 and PyQt 5.14.2).

```
class Gui(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Gui, self).__init__()
        uic.loadUi("gui.ui", self)

        # ...

        self.actionExit = self.findChild(QtWidgets.QAction, "actionExit")
        self.actionExit.triggered.connect(self.closeEvent)

        # ...

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        reply = QMessageBox.question(self, 'Quit?',
                                     'Are you sure you want to quit?',
                                     QMessageBox.Yes | QMessageBox.No, QMessageBox.No)

        if reply == QMessageBox.Yes:
            if not type(event) == bool:
                event.accept()
            else:
                sys.exit()
        else:
            if not type(event) == bool:
                event.ignore()
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to close an PyQt5 app from a menu:

1. When menu event triggered call: `self.MainWindow.close()` (or what window do you want to close
2. Add this code before `sys.exit(app.exec())`: `self.MainWindow.closeEvent = lambda event:self.closeEvent(event)`
3. Declare `def closeEvent(self,event):` method when you really want to close call `event.accept()` (and perhaps `return 1`) and if you don't want to close the window call `event.ignore()` (not `event.reject()` (it's not working for me))

Answer (score 0):

```
def exit_window(self, event):
    close = QtWidgets.QMessageBox.question(self,
                                           "QUIT?",
                                           "Are you sure want to STOP and EXIT?",
                                           QtWidgets.QMessageBox.Yes | QtWidgets.QMessageBox.No)
    if close == QtWidgets.QMessageBox.Yes:
        # event.accept()
        sys.exit()
    else:
        pass
```

Comment: After going through all the answers, I decided to make a simple improvement. Hope it helps someone else facing the same problem in future. Thanks to all.

Answer (score 0):

you need add this line is line to CreateUi your function

```
QMainWindow.closeEvent = self.closeEvent
```