# In PyQt5 how to control the Windows close button event?

Tags: python, pyqt5

I would like to give a choice if the user is sure to close the app, when the Windows close button is being pressed? So far I've coded this, which prompting that the App is about to quit, but I couldn't catch the event or make the App wait until the user confirms. I'm pretty new to this, can anyone help PLEASE.
Here is my code,

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import sys

class Ui_MainWindow(object):


    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        ##
        #......some more codes
        ##
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

        app.aboutToQuit.connect(self.closeEvent)


    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        ## codes



    def closeEvent(self):
        print("User has clicked the red x on the main window")
        ## HERE I WANT TO GIVE AN OPTION TO THE USER IF THEY REALLY WANT TO QUIT
        ## AND ON THIS TIME THE MAIN APP/ MAIN WINDOW NEEDS TO BE ON AS IT IS


if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: I've used Nathan's code below, but now it's giving me the error , TypeError: closeEvent() missing 1 required positional argument: 'event'

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PyQt5 closeEvent method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40622095/pyqt5-closeevent-method)

Answer (score 3):

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40622095/pyqt5-closeevent-method) describes how it should be done.

In short here's the answer from [furas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1832058/furas)

(I used PyQt4.QtGui, but I think this is the exact same as PyQt5.QtWidgets for this application)

```
import sys

from PyQt4.QtGui import QApplication, QMessageBox, QMainWindow, QAction


class  Ui_MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):

        QMainWindow.__init__(self)

    def setupUI(self):


        self.setGeometry(500, 300, 700, 700)

        self.setWindowTitle("window")


        finish = QAction("Quit", self)
        finish.triggered.connect(self.closeEvent)

        menubar = self.menuBar()
        fmenu = menubar.addMenu("File")
        fmenu.addAction(finish)

    def retranslateUi(self):
        ## codes
        codes = "___"


    def closeEvent(self, event):
        close = QMessageBox.question(self,
                                     "QUIT",
                                     "Sure?",
                                      QMessageBox.Yes | QMessageBox.No)
        if close == QMessageBox.Yes:
            event.accept()
        else:
            event.ignore()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Ui_MainWindow()
    window.setupUI()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: this is not exactly the solution of that problem

Comment: Don't change the problem. You're using
class  Ui_MainWindow(QMainWindow):
instead of
class Ui_MainWindow(object):

Answer (score 1):

For PyQt5:
There is 2 options in my solution, first one is for the "x" button, second one is for menu button, decide which better for you.
Based on Natan's answer [exitEvent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48620664/in-pyqt5-how-to-control-the-windows-close-button-event)

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMessageBox, QMainWindow, QAction

class window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):

        super().__init__()

    def createUI(self):


        self.setGeometry(500, 300, 700, 700)

        self.setWindowTitle("window")


        quit = QAction("Quit", self)
        quit.triggered.connect(self.exit_window)

        menubar = self.menuBar()
        fmenu = menubar.addMenu("File")
        fmenu.addAction(quit)

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        close = QMessageBox()
        close.setText("You sure?")
        close.setStandardButtons(QMessageBox.Yes | QMessageBox.Cancel)
        close = close.exec()

        if close == QMessageBox.Yes:
            event.accept()
        else:
            event.ignore()

    def exit_window(self, event):
        close = QtWidgets.QMessageBox.question(self,
                                            "QUIT?",
                                            "Are you sure want to STOP and EXIT?",
                                            QtWidgets.QMessageBox.Yes | QtWidgets.QMessageBox.No)
        if close == QtWidgets.QMessageBox.Yes:
            # event.accept()
            sys.exit()
        else:
            pass


main = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = window()
window.createUI()
window.show()
sys.exit(main.exec_())
```